# Setting Cookies does not work in production Vuejs, vuecookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, cookies, vuejs3

Im using Vue.js 3 & the vue-cookies package  [Vue Cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies)

this is how im setting the cookies in the app

in main.js

```
import VueCookies from "vue-cookies";
app.use(VueCookies, { expires: "35min" });
```

in login.vue

```
const $cookies = inject("$cookies");

const handleLogin = async () => {

try{
const res = await axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/sellers/login",
            data: {
                Email: email.value,
                Password: password.value,
            },
            // withCredentials: true,
        });

       let token = res.data.token;
        // $cookies.set("jwt", token);  //---->method 1

        const storeToken = useLocalStorage("token", {
            token: res.data.token,
        });
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
        });
        let storedToken = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("token"));

        $cookies.set("jwt", storedToken.token);  ///---> method 2

        console.log("getting the cookie");
        let y = $cookies.get("jwt");
        console.log(y);
}

catch(error){
}
```

i've tried storing the cookie in local storage then retrieving and setting it from there (method 2) because i thought the problem was method 1

the results of `console.log(y)` is null

however,i have confirmed the token is in local storage

Both Method 1 & 2 work when the app is running via the Vite development server

After building for production and serving the assets in dist with nodejs, it does not work

what im i doing wrong or haven't done?

i can see the response from the node.js server and even save them in localstorage (like the token)

i can also retrieve the token from localstorage

setting the token from localstorage (method 2) or setting it direct from the response (method 1) is what is not happening

i appreciate your help

Comment: Did my solution provide any help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't create authentication cookies or save any kind of authorization token this way. It makes a good vulnerability for XSS attacks. You should try to set the cookie from your backend with the [`httpOnly`](https://www.cookiepro.com/knowledge/httponly-cookie/) attribute which is not possible from the client side.

Regarding your problem, it's quite difficult to say what could be the problem on production. My best guess is that your production environment is using `https` and your cookie is being set insecurely by the package you are using as its the default. Therefor, it is only accessible when using `http` which you are probably using for development.

Try to set the config to use secure cookies when your `import.meta.env.PROD` equals true like this example below:

```
$cookies.config('35m', '', '', import.meta.env.PROD)
```

You should also make sure that the correct domain is set so it's accessible from the client.

Comment: i tried your solution but it didn't work for me.
i switched to using JWT

Comment: JWTs are fine but please make sure to understand the first part of my solution because if you aren't saving it into a `httpOnly` cookie you will still be vulnerable to XSS attacks. :)

Comment: i set to httpOnly, and works fine in dev mode
but
fails in production mode. the cookies are there but the app/package does not pick them up